# How to display "heavy" images in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-image

I need to display some images in a RecyclerView.
These images should be rendered "on the fly" as user is scrolling the list. Rendering each image takes a long time: 50-500ms. Before the image is displayed to the user, a progress bar is displayed.

Due to the long rendering time this part is placed into an AsyncTask.

See the code below:

```java
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView myImg;
        ProgressBar myProgressBar;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(itemView);
            myImg = view.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
            myProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {  
            Bitmap bitmap = longRenderingFunction();
            holder.myImg.post(() -> {
                holder.myImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                holder.myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If the user is scrolling the list slowly, e.g. 1-2 screens per second, the images are loaded correctly. Sometimes one can notice the progress bar, which quickly disappears.

But if the user is scrolling very fast, the images appear and then are replaced, sometimes two times:

[image: example]

In general it is clear, that on fast scrolling:

- Many `onBindViewHolder` are called and multiple `AsyncTasks` per recyclable item `ViewHolder` are started.
- Even a new `onBindViewHolder` is triggered for the same item, the old `AsyncTask` keep running
- Then `AsyncTasks` for the same `ViewHolder` are completing one after another.
- Each `AsyncTask` puts its own resulting bitmap to the `ImageView`.

My intentions would be:

- minimum: do not `setImageBitmap` from the outdated `AsyncTasks`
- maximum: to stop already outdated `AsyncTasks` as soon as possible to save system resources

I would appreciate to hear some hints or maybe solutions for this problem.

Comment: You are on the right track. Just cancel the `AsyncTask`. The tricky part is where to hold a reference to the `AsyncTask` to let you cancel it. I think you should create a `HashMap<int, AsyncTask>` in your adapter to store each task for each position.

Comment: While you can manage this yourself, I highly recommend checking out libraries such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which are intended to manage a lot of the heavy lifting for you when loading images.

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer It is a good idea to cancel the tasks. Here I'm still missing the right way to do it  in Android. My renderer is packed into a pretty compact runnable. ``AsyncTask.execute`` is also a compact construction. I'd like to keep it compact. If I create a _correct_ ``AsyncTask``, then it becomes a monster with ``doInBackground`` etc. So here I'm thinking about [``ExecutorService``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which can return ``Future<>`` and which can be canceled any time. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.

## Stop flickering

The first part is pretty simple:

A simple index was introduced:

```java
int loadingPosition;
```

At the beginning of `onBindViewHolder` the current position is saved:

```java
holder.loadingPosition = position;
```

Before switching the bitmap the current position is checked against the last started. If a new task has been already started, the index was changed beforehand, then the image will not be updated:

```java
if (holder.loadingPosition == position) {
    holder.myImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

## Improve performance

To prevent the task to run further when not needed a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object was introduced. It allows to manage the started task, while `AsyncTask` does not:

```java
Future<?> future;
```

Start the async task via [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of `AsyncTask`:

```java
holder.future = executor.submit(() -> { ...
```

Stopping the running task, if it is still running:

```java
if ((holder.future != null) && (!holder.future.isDone()))
    holder.future.cancel(true);
```

## Complete code

The whole code looks like that:

```java
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView myImg;
        ProgressBar myProgressBar;
        int loadingPosition;
        Future<?> future;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(itemView);
            myImg = view.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
            myProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.loadingPosition = position;
        if ((holder.future != null) && (!holder.future.isDone()))
            holder.future.cancel(true);
        holder.myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.future = executor.submit(() -> {
            Bitmap bitmap = longRenderingFunction();
            holder.myImg.post(() -> {
                if (holder.loadingPosition == position) {
                    holder.myImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    holder.myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Maybe using the both methods is a little bit overkill, but it provides some level of insurance.